# Intune Enroll Device Issue in Andriod

Tags: intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I have Installed Intune Company Portal App  in Android Vivo Mobile and also registered the Device and Sign in but when I Login with My Client app and when press enroll device then its appearing this message even I have installed this app[image: Here is the Screen Short of the Message]

Now how i can Enroll my Client device app ?